# GROUP BY unavailable in SuperSet

Tags: apache-superset

Could you help me please with an issue I have in SuperSet? The GROUP BY functionality is not available in the interface. I attached there an example with the actual layout I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WH60.png)

Should I have some special configuration in order to have it visible?

---